# JAX-RS (Reasteasy) Response.readEntity throws: IllegalStateException: RESTEASY003290: Entity is not backed by an input stream

Tags: java, rest, junit, mocking, jax-rs

I have JUnit test of a method which send a JAX-RS `POST` call.
To be independent from external resources I have mocked the REST client and said that a dummy response should be returned. Works great, no problem. But:

When calling `myResponse.readEntity(String.class)` I always get the following Exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: RESTEASY003290: Entity is not backed by an input stream

Here is my code snippet which fails:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SimpleTest {

    @Test
    public void testReadResponse() {
        final JsonObject responseContent = new JsonObject();
        responseContent.add("field", new JsonPrimitive("This is a JSON for testing."));
        final String expected = responseContent.toString();
        final Response.ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok()
            .entity(responseContent.toString())
            .header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        final Response dummyResponse = builder.build();
        final String result = dummyResponse.readEntity(String.class); // <-- Exception is thrown here!
        assertThat("JSON Strings are not identical.", result, is(expected));
    }
}
```

and the Stacktrace:

```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: RESTEASY003290: Entity is not backed by an input stream
    at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.readEntity(BuiltResponse.java:230)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.BuiltResponse.readEntity(BuiltResponse.java:219)
    at de.me.myproject.SimpleTest.testReadResponse(SimpleTest.java:43)
```

In my production code, which calls a not mocked REST API, it returns a automatically build response, where the `.readEntity(String.class)` method works fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`Response`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html) is an abstract class and RESTEasy has different sub classes for client and server, see [`BuiltResponse`](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-rc-1/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/specimpl/BuiltResponse.html) and [`ClientResponse`](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-rc-1/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/client/ClientResponse.html). Not all methods are supported in each sub class.

[`Response#readEntity`](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-rc-1/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity(java.lang.Class)) needs to be backed by an input stream:

> Method throws an `ProcessingException` if the content of the message cannot be mapped to an entity of the requested type and `IllegalStateException` in case the entity is not backed by an input stream or if the original entity input stream has already been consumed without `buffering` the entity data prior consuming.

A `BuiltResponse` is never backed by an input stream and therefore you get a `IllegalStateException`.

You can use [`Response#getEntity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#getEntity--), it doesn't need an input stream.

Comment: getEntity() does solve the problem. Adding to getEntity(), one can typecast the getEntity() response into custom POJO and then use the usual getXXX() to perform `assertEquals(typecastedResponse.getXXX(), expected)`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the hint.

I ended up with the following that worked for me. Simply return a new instance of the class below.

```
class MockResponse extends BuiltResponse {
    private Object entity;

    public MockResponse() {
    }
    public MockResponse(Object entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }
    @Override
    public <T> T readEntity(Class<T> type) {
        return (T) entity;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T readEntity(Class<T> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] anns) {
        return (T) entity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating a mockResponse like above is not helping me. Not sure where am I going wrong :(

Answer (score 1):

Today I went through the same situation. Finally I have the below solution. Just mock the readEntity method in BuiltResponse to return whatever response you need. It worked for me.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.